# How to set the background color of a whole line in tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to set the background color of the whole line using the `colorbox` but only the word's background is set and the remaining is not set.

As an analogy from the HTML, I'm trying to do `<td style="background=gray;width=100;">` i.e. the background coloring will extend from left to the rightmost side.

How to do it? Using `tcolorbox` is preferred but not strictly necessary.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white] 
    \colorbox{gray}{Engine}\par
  4 pistons, 1600cc
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also (as you seems to do in the HTML example) use a tabular (probably a `tabularx`, or one of the powerful tabular-like new packages). I tend to think of a tcolorbox more like  `<div>...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could choose one of the following methods:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{mystyle/.style={colback=gray, sharp corners, boxrule=0mm, 
left=0mm, right=0mm, bottom=0mm, top=0mm, %boxsep=0mm,
before skip=2mm,% Default value of 'top'
 after skip=0.5\baselineskip,
},}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,
title={Engine as title}, colbacktitle=gray, coltitle=black,
] 
\colorbox{gray}{Engine old}\par
\begin{tcolorbox}[mystyle] Engine as tcolorbox \end{tcolorbox} \par
\colorbox{gray}{\rlap{Engine as colorbox}\hspace{\linewidth}\hspace{-2\fboxsep}}
4 pistons, 1600cc
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The first method i.e. `Engine as tcolorbox ` works quite fine.  It's application looks similar to the HTML too. That's fine.

Comment: I am glad to hear. ;)